# How to import contacts from Yahoo and Outlook in Django 1.5 App?

Tags: python, django, outlook, yahoo, gdata

How can i import **contacts** from Yahoo and Outlook account in Django app? i have imported contacts from Google via **gdata** api. Is there anything like that for Yahoo and Outlook ? I would like to hear from you geeks.

Answer (score -2):

Look for [django-contacts-import](https://github.com/eldarion/django-contacts-import)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: That is a review comment for your answers, answers are expected to be more elaborate rather than just a link

Comment: I don't necessarily agree. The app does exactly what the user wants, as is without any instructions needed.

The user isn't asking how to do what he wants, he's simply asking if there is an api/app for that.

Comment: this build is failing